# Graphically solving a linear programming problem

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

I try to realize the graphical linear programming method.
Here is my code

```
Clear[GraphicalMethod]
GraphicalMethod[L_?VectorQ, A_?MatrixQ, b_?VectorQ, vars_?VectorQ] := 
 Module[{obj = L.vars, 
   cond = Thread[A.vars <= b]~Join~Thread[vars >= 0], r, sol, x1, x2},
  sol = Maximize[{L.vars, Thread[A.vars <= b]~Join~Thread[0 <= vars]},
     vars];
  x1 = Max[
    First@vars /. Solve[#, First@vars] & /@ 
     Thread[First /@ (A.vars) == b]];
  x2 = Max[
    Last@vars /. Solve[#, Last@vars] & /@ 
     Thread[Last /@ (A.vars) == b]];
  r = Sequence[Evaluate@{First@vars, 0, x1}, 
    Evaluate@{Last@vars, 0, x2}];
  Print[sol];
  Manipulate[
   Show[RegionPlot[And @@ cond, Evaluate@r, 
     BoundaryStyle -> {Blue, Thick}], 
    ContourPlot[Evaluate@Apply[Equal, cond, 1], Evaluate@r, 
     ContourStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}}],
    ContourPlot[obj == k, Evaluate@r, ContourStyle -> {{Red, Thick}}]
    ], {{k, N@(First@sol)/2, "Objective Function"}, 0, First@sol, 
    Appearance -> "Open"}]]

GraphicalMethod[{12, 15}, {{4, 3}, {2, 5}}, {12, 10}, {x[1],x[2]}]
```

It can work for this example, but if we have conditions for 1 variable

```
GraphicalMethod[{12, 15}, {{4, 0}, {2, 5}}, {12, 10}, {x[1],x[2]}]
```

it

```
x1 = Max[First@vars /. Solve[#, First@vars] & /@ 
    Thread[First /@ (A.vars) == b]];
x2 = Max[Last@vars /. Solve[#, Last@vars] & /@ 
    Thread[Last /@ (A.vars) == b]];
```

gives False and function will not work. I understand why, but I haven't another ideas how to get the optimal interval `r` for `x[1]` and `x[2]`. Can you help me?

Comment: Have you seen [`LinearProgramming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming.html?q=LinearProgramming) which might ease the input of the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the following does more or less the same and is much easier to read:

```
Clear[GraphicalMethod];
GraphicalMethod[c_?VectorQ, m_?MatrixQ, b_?VectorQ] :=
 Module[{k, eqs, l2, l1, jeq, x = {x1, x2}},
  k = c.LinearProgramming[-c, m, Thread[{b, -1}]];
  eqs = Reduce /@ Thread[m.x == b];
  jeq = Join[eqs, {k == x.c}];
  {l2, l1} = Max@Flatten[Solve /@ (jeq /. # -> 0)][[All, 2]] & /@ x;
  Manipulate[
   Show[
    RegionPlot [And@@ Thread[m.x <= b], {x1, 0, l1}, {x2, 0, l2}],
    ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqs,           {x1, 0, l1}, {x2, 0, l2}],
    ContourPlot[k1 == x.c,              {x1, 0, l1}, {x2, 0, l2},ContourStyle -> Red]],
   {{k1, k/2, "Objective Function"}, 0, k}]]

c = {12, 15};
m = {{4, 3}, {2, 5}};
b = {12, 8};

GraphicalMethod[c, m, b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Brilliant :) I'm very grateful to you

Comment: One more question: maybe, it's better to write `k = c.LinearProgramming[-c, m, Thread[{b, -1}]]` ?

Comment: @luck_liv Why do you think that that is better?

Comment: `LinearProgramming[c,m,b]`
finds a vector `x` that minimizes the quantity `c.x` subject to the constraints `m.x>=b` and `x>=0`.

So, if it's maximize problem, we need to minimize the quantity `-c.x` subject to the constraints `m.x<=b` and `x>=0`.

GraphicalMethod[{2, 4}, {{-2, 3}, {1, 1}, {3, -2}}, {12, 9, 12}]
gives the wrong answer if `k = c.LinearProgramming[c, m, b]`

Comment: @luck_liv Oh, I see. You're right. Going to edit the code. Thanks a lot for checking it

Comment: Two answers to allow for double points?

Comment: @P.Fonseca I don't think so. Perhaps the reason is that they are mostly unrelated. Or just because I believe that posting two different approaches in the same answer requires too much explanation on the whys and hows

Answer (score 5):

The following is a quick and dirty patch. You can do something more elegant taking it as a template:

```
Clear[GraphicalMethod]
GraphicalMethod[L_?VectorQ, A_?MatrixQ, b_?VectorQ, vars_?VectorQ] := 
 Module[{obj = L.vars, cond = Thread[A.vars <= b]~Join~Thread[vars >= 0], r, sol, x1, x2},
   sol = Maximize[{L.vars, Thread[A.vars <= b]~Join~Thread[0 <= vars]}, vars];
  x1 = Max[First@vars /. Solve[#, First@vars] & /@ Thread[First /@ (A.vars) == b]];
  x2 = Max[Last@vars /. Solve[#, Last@vars] & /@ Thread[Last /@ (A.vars) == b]];
  x2 = First@ If[NumericQ[x2], {x2}, Evaluate[ Last[vars]] /. (Solve[
        obj == sol[[1]] /. Evaluate[First[vars]] -> 0])];
  x1 = First@ If[NumericQ[x1], {x1}, Evaluate[First[vars]] /. (Solve[
        obj == sol[[1]] /. Evaluate[Last[vars]] -> 0])];
  r = Sequence[Evaluate@{First@vars, 0, x1}, Evaluate@{Last@vars, 0, x2}];

  Print[sol];
  Manipulate[Show[
    RegionPlot[And @@ cond, Evaluate@r, BoundaryStyle -> {Blue, Thick}], 
    ContourPlot[Evaluate@Apply[Equal, cond, 1], Evaluate@r, ContourStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}}],
    ContourPlot[obj == k, Evaluate@r, 
     ContourStyle -> {{Red, Thick}}]], {{k, N@(First@sol)/2, 
     "Objective Function"}, 0, First@sol, Appearance -> "Open"}]]
```

And then

```
Row[{
  GraphicalMethod[{12, 15}, {{4, 3}, {2, 5}}, {12, 10}, {x[1], x[2]}],
  GraphicalMethod[{12, 15}, {{4, 0}, {2, 5}}, {12, 10}, {x[1], x[2]}],
  GraphicalMethod[{12, 15}, {{4, 0}, {0, 5}}, {12, 10}, {x[1], x[2]}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]